# Why is physical security key helpful, since most accounts have alternative 2FA methods a hacker could use?

Tags: multi-factor, phishing

I would like to know why a physical security key is useful to have as default 2FA method given most accounts have some form of account recovery/alternative 2FA method. Google has had a bunch of alternatives, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security is only as strong as the weakest link in the attacker's way. If you have an account with 2FA options of "FIDO2/Webauthn" (Yubikey/Titan Key/etc.) and "SMS", your account is at greater risk than if you remove one of those factors. *Either one* of those alone is stronger than both; it's true that SMS is generally much weaker than Webauthn, but it's not *strictly* weaker; there are attacks against a hardware token (most notably, just stealing it, or accessing an unattended machine with the token plugged in) that might not work against SMS.

This implies an obvious conclusion: **you should not enable any authentication factors you don't need!** As a general rule, it's a good idea to have two options for second factor, just like *in practice* you usually have two options for first factor (password or password-reset-via-email), but that's so you don't lock yourself out of the account by accident. It's higher risk of an attacker getting *in* to do add more second factors. The exception would be if you can add it as a "third factor", where e.g. *both* SMS and Yubikey are required, not just *either* of them. Almost no services support this, though.

Some sites force you to enable a factor you don't want (usually SMS), no matter what else you do, and don't let you disable it later. As weird as it sounds, on sites like that, adding a Yubikey is actually making your account **very slightly less secure!** (With that said, see the next paragraph too.) Other sites will, after adding two second factors of your choice (maybe a second Yubikey, or a TOTP ["Google Authenticator"] code generator, or push notifications in an app), let you remove the default second factor (almost always SMS, for sites like that). You should do so when possible.

The one advantage of adding Webauthn providers (be they hardware tokens or OS-based platform authentication) even when you also have a weaker second factor enabled is phishing protection. If you go to a site that looks identical to the usual login page, and you enter your credentials, and you reach to touch your Yubikey before noticing that it isn't even flashing and the site instead says "please enter the SMS code we just sent you", **that should be a warning sign that you are being phished!** You can avoid the risk by never using the weaker second factor unless by your own choice (e.g. because you lost your Yubikey). However, having two different options of second factor does still mean there are two different types of credential an attacker could try to obtain, or bypass, to log in as you. Since phishing is a really common vector for account compromise, it is in fact a good idea to enable a phishing-proof second factor even if you also have a non-phishing-proof one; just make sure you always use the phishing-proof one (and be *VERY* suspicious if the login site doesn't offer it!) and and that the alternative is as strong as possible (please not SMS... it's just not made for that at all.)